# Cannot launch my asp.net core application in Production

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate

I have a Windows Server 2016 VM environment I just deployed a .NET Core application to. I cannot launch the application in my production environment.

Initially the error I was getting was around port 5000 being in use, and Kestrel not being able to use the port. I went back into the development environment, and configured Kestrel with an OpenSSL certificate. 
I exported the certificate to my production environment, and the port 5000 error disappeared. However, I am getting some connection issues even after checking to ensure that the connection string is ok, and the relevant services are running on the server.
I did a Dotnet .\Asp.Web.dll command from Command Prompt, and I keep getting connection error. The .Net Core Host starts up, but after about a minute, I get a popup saying it has stopped working. Included is the log from the command:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
        {
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.UseHttps("myCertificate.pfx", "password");
            });
        });
}
```

.................
.............
Key ring with default key {xxxxxxxxxxxxx} was loaded during application startup.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages in type MvcJsonOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch AllowCombiningAuthorizeFilters in type MvcOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch AllowBindingHeaderValuesToNonStringModelTypes in type MvcOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch AllowValidatingTopLevelNodes in type MvcOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch InputFormatterExceptionPolicy in type MvcOptions is using compatibility value MalformedInputExceptions for version Version_2_1
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch SuppressBindingUndefinedValueToEnumType in type MvcOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch EnableEndpointRouting in type MvcOptions is using default value False
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch MaxValidationDepth in type MvcOptions is using default value (null)
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch AllowShortCircuitingValidationWhenNoValidatorsArePresent in type MvcOptions is using default value False
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiBehaviorOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch SuppressMapClientErrors in type ApiBehaviorOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiBehaviorOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch SuppressUseValidationProblemDetailsForInvalidModelStateResponses in type ApiBehaviorOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiBehaviorOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch AllowInferringBindingSourceForCollectionTypesAsFromQuery in type ApiBehaviorOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.RazorPagesOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch AllowAreas in type RazorPagesOptions is using explicitly configured value True
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.RazorPagesOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch AllowMappingHeadRequestsToGetHandler in type RazorPagesOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.RazorPagesOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch AllowDefaultHandlingForOptionsRequests in type RazorPagesOptions is using default value False
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngineOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch AllowRecompilingViewsOnFileChange in type RazorViewEngineOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcViewOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch SuppressTempDataAttributePrefix in type MvcViewOptions is using compatibility value True for version Version_2_1
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcViewOptions[0]
      Compatibility switch AllowRenderingMaxLengthAttribute in type MvcViewOptions is using default value False
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBinderFactory[12]
      Registered model binder providers, in the following order: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BinderTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ServicesModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.HeaderModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FloatingPointTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.EnumTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.CancellationTokenModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ByteArrayModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormFileModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.FormCollectionModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.KeyValuePairModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.DictionaryModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ArrayModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.CollectionModelBinderProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinderProvider
Application startup exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (53): The network path was not found
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Asp.Web.Startup.GetComponents() in C:\Asp.Web\Startup.cs:line 275
   at Asp.Web.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in C:\Asp.Web\Startup.cs:line 264
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:53,State:0,Class:20
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
      Application startup exception
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (53): The network path was not found
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Asp.Web.Startup.GetComponents() in C:\Asp.Web\Startup.cs:line 275
   at Asp.Web.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in C:\Asp.Web\Startup.cs:line 264
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:53,State:0,Class:20
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[5]
      Hosting shutdown

Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Asp.Web.Startup.GetComponents() in C:\Asp.Web\Startup.cs:line 275
   at Asp.Web.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in C:\Asp.Web\Startup.cs:line 264
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at Asp.Web.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Asp.Web\Program.cs:line 12

Comment: Looks to me like it can't connect to your database. _A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (53): The network path was not found_ looks like the important bit of the log. It occurs more than once

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing connection string in your config on production or credentials are wrong. You should check if everything is ok in your `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Production.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, for the confirmation that it was indeed a connection issue. My DBContext OnConfiguring override method in a Model project was using hard-coded connection string to a database in my development environment. I had changed the connection strings in my AppSettings.Json but I could not see/change this in my production environment.